# jQuery rotation function not firing.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery extension:

```
(function ($) { //jQuery plugin extension

    jQuery.fn.rotate = function(degree, maxDegree) {
        this.css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});
        this.css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});

          // Animate rotation with a recursive call
        rotation = setInterval(function() { 
            if (degree < (maxDegree/2)) { 
                $(this).rotate(++degree);
            } else {
                clearInterval(rotation);
            }
        },5);
    };
}(jQuery));
```

And I'm calling it like this:

```
$('#test').live('mouseover',function() {
                $(this).rotate(0, 360);
            });
```

But it doesn't fire, here is a JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/neuroflux/8vZqr/

( Note, the fiddle won't run because of the `live()` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling the function you have your plugin in:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.rotate = function(degree, maxDegree) {
        //...
    };
}(jQuery)); // <-- call
```

Furthermore, `this` inside the `setInterval` method does not refer to the selected elements anymore, but to `window`. You have to keep a reference to `this`:

```
var $self = this;
var rotation = setInterval(function() { 
    if (degree < (maxDegree/2)) { 
        $self.rotate(++degree);
     //...
};
```

I would als make `rotation` a local variable (with `var`) otherwise you will get in trouble if the function fires on several elements.

As for your fiddle, you did not select jQuery to use as library.

If this is all fixed, [it works →](http://jsfiddle.net/8vZqr/10/) .

Comment: Oops, I have - I forgot to put it into SO. Still doesn't fire : (

Answer (score 1):

You can also have a look to that jQuery plugin :

http://www.zachstronaut.com/projects/rotate3di/

Comment: I'm after a 2d rotation, that plugin is *huge*, I only need basic functionality..