# How to add element rotation to jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, css

I'm trying to do a simple extension of jQuery to allow image rotation via `$("element").rotate(arbitraryNumber);` later on.

From my understanding this is the correct method for setting the transform properties using jquery. I get the feeling I've forgotten something obvious..

```
    jQuery.fn.rotate=function(deg){
                        this.css({'transform': 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'});
                        this.css({'-ms-transform': 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'});
                        this.css({'-moz-transform': 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'});
                        this.css({'-o-transform': 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'}); 
                        this.css({'-webkit-transform': 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'});
                        return this; 
                    };
```

**EDIT: CODE REDUCTION**

```
jQuery.fn.rotate=
function(deg){
                $(this).css({ 'transform': 'rotate('+deg+'deg)','-ms-transform': 'rotate('+deg+'deg)', '-moz-transform': 'rotate('+deg+'deg)', 
                    '-o-transform': 'rotate('+deg+'deg)', '-webkit-transform': 'rotate('+deg+'deg)' });
                return this;
             };
```

**FURTHER EDIT** Sorry my mistake, there was just a typo further in the calling.

Comment: Is the code not working? What does or doesn't it do?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860076/jquery-rotation-function-not-firing

Comment: And your problem is? I just used your code to rotate the body of this page with no issue.

Comment: Quick tip: You could combine all those `css()` calls into one: `this.css({'transform' : 'rotate blah', '-ms-transform' : 'rotate blah', ...});`

Comment: @JapanPro, no, inside a `jQuery.fn` function, `this` is the jQuery set.

Comment: @meagar The code is not working, it is called once a second for a little clock function.

Comment: @john: i thought it should work too! i'm using latest firefox.. not understanding

Comment: @nickf thanks much, i didn't know you could chain them.

Comment: Share your code that calls this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(function( $ ){
$.fn.rotate = function(deg) {
    this.css({'transform': 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'});
    this.css({'-ms-transform': 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'});
    this.css({'-moz-transform': 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'});
    this.css({'-o-transform': 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'}); 
    this.css({'-webkit-transform': 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'});
    return this; 
};
})( jQuery );

//example
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sample').rotate(60);
});
```

Comment: Yes, you need to run the function after the content loads.

Comment: @derp derp @ me. complete blindess, I totally forget to use # when i called it. sorry